# How to join with two tables and two or more columns (Ms Access)?

Tags: sql, ms-access, join

Here are my tables which I want to join for a query.

Table 1 name *Hasta*:

```
ID  -----   AdiSoyadi
1   -----   Mesut AKTAS
2   -----   Orhan Dogan
3   -----   Ali Veli
...
```

Table 2 name *islemler*:

```
Hasta_ID --------  islem_Tarihi------ Aciklama
1----------------- 12.12.2015---------Explain 1>
1------------------16.12.2015 --------Explain 2
2------------------20.12.2015---------Explain 3
2------------------19.12.2015---------Explain 4
3------------------18.12.2015---------Explain 5
3------------------01.01.2016---------Explain 6
3------------------02.01.2016---------Explain 7 
......
```

I want to this result:

```
islem_Tarihi------Hasta_ID----------AdiSoyadi-------Aciklama
02.01.2016--------3-----------------Ali Veli--------Explain 7
20.15.2015--------2-----------------Orhan Dogan-----Explain 3
16.12.2015--------1-----------------Mesut AKTAS-----Explain 2
```

Here is the my SQL query which is not working as expected:

```
SELECT t1.islem_Tarihi,t2.AdiSoyadi,t1.Aciklama
FROM islemler t1
inner join Hasta t2
    on t2.ID=t1.Hasta_ID
inner join (SELECT MAX(islem_Tarihi) AS Mak,AdiSoyadi
                  From islemler,Hasta
                  Where Hasta.ID=islemler.Hasta_ID
                  GROUP BY AdiSoyadi) t3
ON t2.AdiSoyadi=t3.AdiSoyadi And t1.islem_Tarihi=t3.Mak
```

How should my query be formulated for that result as described above?

Comment: When a user says to me "It's not working", I send them back to get a *real* error description.

Comment: The code in the OP appears to be correct (e.g. in MySQL), but not sure if you could get it to run in ms-access without putting t3 in as a separate query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to want the most recent row from `hasta`.  Here is one method:

```
select i.islem_Tarihi, h.AdiSoyadi, h.Aciklama
from hasta as h inner join
     islemler as i
     on h.id = i.hasta_id
where i.islem_Tarihi = (select max(i2.islem_Tarihi
                        from islemler as i2
                        where i2.id = i.id
                       )
order by h.id desc;
```

Comment: Thank you! You lead me to the solution.
Difference from your suggestion is we dont have islem_Tarihi column in Hasta table.I managed the problem with this query
SELECT i.islem_Tarihi, h.AdiSoyadi, i.Aciklama
FROM hasta AS h INNER JOIN islemler AS i ON h.ID = i.Hasta_ID
WHERE (((i.islem_Tarihi)=(select max(i2.islem_Tarihi)
                        from islemler as i2
                        where i2.Hasta_ID = h.ID
                       )))
ORDER BY i.islem_Tarihi DESC;

Comment: @M.AKTAS . . . I fixed the answer.